# Why is "this" giving an error?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to go to second activity using button. Here is the code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent();
                i.setClassName(this,"com.example.ankit.layouts.SecondAtivity");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting an error in `i.setClassName()` as "cannot resolve this method", but when I use `MainActivity.this` I do not get any error. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

`this` does not work because you are in an anonymous class of type `OnClickListener` which is not what `setClassName` expect. When you are writing `MainActivity.this` you are explicitly telling java to take the `this` from the encapsulating class of type `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondAtivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```